# Spring RequestMapping

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc

Currently every page in my current location has a web-url as follows.

/test/test

In my controller the rest mapping works just fine and finds a page test.jsp.

/test/test.jsp does not work.

Now I need to do redirects from old urls to new urls. These have .jsp in every one of their urls. When I set up the url I get a 404 error. When I remove the .jsp heading it at least hits my request mapping.

I need to find a way where the controller can recognize jsp's with or without the jsp extension. I am trying to then redirct.

Here is part of my application context.

```
<beans:bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
</beans:bean>
```

Here is the setting in my web.xml.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write a [servlet `Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) that checks if the request path ends with ".jsp", and if so does a redirect to the same path without ".jsp".